# How to select columns with other name in linq?

Tags: sql-server, linq, multiple-columns

I select my records in `SQL Server Query` as you seen below:

```
SELECT  ProductName 'Some Name1' ,
        Payment 'Some Name2'
FROM    dbo.PrefactorProduct
```

Is there a way to select records like that in `linq` queries?

Answer (score 2):

You can project result from your query to an Anonymous type and use different alias/field names for your fields.

```
var query = db.PrefactorProduct
              .Select(r=> new 
                     {
                       SomeName1 = r.ProductName, 
                       SomeName2 = r.Payment
                     });
```

But if you are trying to format your result set for displaying purpose then you should look in to assigning column names for your grid/ data container.

Comment: I know that, but i want to select the result with the excat name that you see in the question. like this `db.PrefactorProduct.Select(r=> new { "some name" = r.ProductName });`

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, you can't. Field Name can't contain spaces